# CSS works locally but not loading on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres, steam

going nuts here... I have an app I've been working on using nitrous.io.  Everything works how it should (CSS appears, I'm able to login to Steam and create an entry in my database).  Great!  So I pushed it to Heroku and now the CSS doesn't appear and I'm unable to login with my Steam account.  The only thing that loads is my Logo (img) and the column names.  Trying to login to steam gives me the "we're sorry but something went wrong" error.  You can see here: http://infinite-brushlands-2505.herokuapp.com/

For starters the entire page should be black, instead it is white.  I've tried all the suggestions I've found on here and can't seem to get any to work.  I've tried switching to the Unicorn webserver and running the rake assets:precompile as well as the rake db:migrate.  Can't seem to figure it out.  Here are the heroku logs.

```
2013-12-26T23:37:21.653856+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-26T23:37:21.653590 #6]  INFO --        omniauth: (steam) Callback phase initiated.                                           
2013-12-26T23:37:21.659893+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-26T23:37:21.659713 #6]  INFO --    OpenID: Error attempting to use stored discovery information: OpenID::TypeURIMismatch 
2013-12-26T23:37:21.659893+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-26T23:37:21.659808 #6]  INFO --  OpenID: Attempting discovery to verify endpoint                                       
2013-12-26T23:37:21.659893+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-26T23:37:21.659879 #6]  INFO --  OpenID: Performing discovery on http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561198060154411 
2013-12-26T23:37:21.851590+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-26T23:37:21.851383 #6]  INFO -- OpenID: Using 'check_authentication' with https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login     
2013-12-26T23:37:21.852288+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-26T23:37:21.852196 #6]  INFO --  OpenID: WARNING: making https request to https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login witho
ut verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.                                                                                                                     
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for   nil:NilClass):                                                                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-steam-1.0.3/lib/omniauth/strategies/steam.rb:39:in `player'                              
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-openid-1.0.1/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:81:in `callback_phase'                   
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'                                    
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'                                            
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'                                             
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                                                                   
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-steam-1.0.3/lib/omniauth/strategies/steam.rb:17:in `block in <class:Steam>'              
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:106:in `instance_eval'                                    
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:106:in `block in compile_stack'                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `each'                                             
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `inject'                                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `compile_stack'                                    
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422434+00:00 app[web.1]:   (eval):7:in `info_stack'                                                                                                        
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:322:in `info'                                             
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:335:in `auth_hash'                                        
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:362:in `callback_phase'                                   
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'                                               
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'                                                          
2013-12-26T23:37:22.422795+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'                                                
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423035+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'                                                          
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423035+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack- 4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'          
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'                                                
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423035+00:00 app[web.1]:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in  `call'                                  
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423035+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord- 4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423035+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'                
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423035+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1500215298515703650__call__callbacks'                                                                                                                                                                          
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'                         
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack- 4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'                         
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'                                          
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'                                     
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'                         
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'                  
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'                   
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'                  
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in  `tagged'                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423729+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'                                              
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'                        
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'                                                       
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport- 4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'                 
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'                            
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'                                                  
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties- 4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'                                              
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'                                  
2013-12-26T23:37:22.423991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:660:in `worker_loop'                                     
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:527:in `spawn_missing_workers'                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:153:in `start'                                           
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'                                               
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'                                                                               
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'                                                                             
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                                                                   
2013-12-26T23:37:22.424448+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                                                                   
2013-12-26T23:37:22.445825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET   path=/auth/steam/callback? _method=post&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_
res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=h ttp%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198060154411&openid.identity=ht
tp%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198060154411&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Finfinite-brushlands-2505.herokuapp.com%2Fauth%2Fsteam%2Fcallback%3F_method%3Dpost
&openid.response_nonce=2013-12-26T23%3A37%3A21Zh2xO6mo%2Bu9aMyRqJc3lvwYrc0ao%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Cret
```

And here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# use Steam OpenID Omniauth gem for authenticating Steam users
gem 'omniauth-steam'

gem 'figaro'

gem 'has_scope'

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'

#cyborg bootswatch theme
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-   bootswatch-rails.git'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:    https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# for pushing to heroku
group :production, :staging do
     gem 'pg'
      gem 'rails_12factor'
    end

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'



ruby "2.0.0"
```

Thanks so much everyone.  Let me know if I need to post more info; I'm pretty new to this!

Comment: what happens when you `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` locally

Comment: Oh interesting.  Now the CSS doesn't appear here either (site is white instead of black), but I am able to login to steam and create a new entry.  Any ideas why this may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're production environment most likely doesn't have these set

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Awesome!  That seemed to do the trick and now the css appears.  For some reason I still get the Steam login error, but that's another problem I suppose.  Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @JesseNewman, could you up vote Andrew for answering your question? Thank you

Comment: @Galuga Sorry but it says I need 15 reputation to do this. :-/